# VS Code Debugging Issue in Electron Forge with Vite Template: Breakpoints Not Binding

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, electron, vite, electron-forge

I've recently initiated a project using Electron Forge with the Vite template. The setup involved the following commands:

```
npm init electron-app@latest my-app -- --template=vite
```

Here's the configuration of my launch.json file:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Electron Main",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/@electron-forge/cli/script/vscode.sh",
      "windows": {
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/@electron-forge/cli/script/vscode.cmd"
      },
      // runtimeArgs will be passed directly to your Electron application
      "runtimeArgs": [],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/main.js",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
    }
  ]
}
```

I can successfully launch my application using the start debugging in VS Coode. Debugger attached also showed in the terminal. However, I encounter a problem with breakpoints in my code. They appear greyed out, suggesting that they are not being bound correctly.

Upon using the troubleshooting option, the Debug Doctor provided the following information:

```
✅ This breakpoint was initially set in:

C:\Users\zhuang\Projects\my-electron-app\src\main.js line 125 column 1

❓ We couldn't find a corresponding source location, but found some other files with the same name:

c:/Users/zhuang/Projects/my-electron-app/src/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js
If this is the same file, you may need to adjust your build tool to correct the paths.
```

I'm seeking advice on how to resolve this issue. Is there a way to adjust the build tool or configuration to enable proper binding of breakpoints?

I attempted to add the following configurations to my launch.json file, but unfortunately, it didn't work as expected.

```
"outFiles": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/src/*.js"
],
"sourceMaps": true,
"sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/esbuild/lib/*": "${workspaceFolder}/.vite/build/*",
}
```

Comment: When I was working on my project using only Electron, debugging in VSCode was not a problem. Now that the project has grown, I want to manage it with Electron Forge, but ironically, I can't debug it anymore.